# Check if elements exists, if not add specific element

Tags: xml, xslt

It's been a while since I've needed XML so I'm struggling with the right xslt to do the following transformation.

This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Dic Version="1">
       <Entry>
        <Text Lang="en">text1</Text>
        <Text Lang="de">text2</Text>
        <Text Lang="fr">text3</Text>
       </Entry>
        <Entry>
         <Text Lang="en">text1</Text>
         <Text Lang="de">text2</Text>
        </Entry>
    </Dic>
```

If `<Text Lang="fr" />` is missing it should be added so the outputs looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Dic Version="1">
       <Entry>
        <Text Lang="en">text1</Text>
        <Text Lang="de">text2</Text>
        <Text Lang="fr">text3</Text>
       </Entry>
        <Entry>
         <Text Lang="en">text1</Text>
         <Text Lang="de">text2</Text>
         <Text Lang="fr"></Text>
        </Entry>
    </Dic>
```

My embarassing  not-working stylesheet:

```
  <xsl:template match="Dic/Entry">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="@Lang=fr"></xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise><Text Lang="fr"></Text></xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show any XSLT you have tried please? Also, will it only be "fr" that could be missing? Could "de" or "en" be missing too? Thanks!

Comment: "en" and "de" could also be missing. Valid point.

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0 or above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any of the three languages could be missing, then I would suggest you do it this way:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:copy>
        <Text Lang="en"><xsl:value-of select="Text[@Lang='en']"/></Text>
        <Text Lang="de"><xsl:value-of select="Text[@Lang='de']"/></Text>
        <Text Lang="fr"><xsl:value-of select="Text[@Lang='fr']"/></Text>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: One additonal question: What would I have to do to copy the attribute "Key" and its attributes of "Entry" also to the output.xml? I tried  <xsl:template match="Entry[@Key='*']" but that doesn't work.

Comment: If Entry has attributes, copy them using `<xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>`. Do this immediately after `<xsl:copy>` and before the `Text` elements.